# HPROF ERROR: Cannot allocate malloc memory

Tags: java, bash, hprof

Running a java program using shell script but it terminates in mid of execution. Getting the below error-

```
 HPROF ERROR: Cannot allocate malloc memory [hprof_util.c:164]
    HPROF TERMINATED PROCESS
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How did you invoke hprof?

Comment: I did not invoke hprof. I'm using DigitalOcean Ubuntu droplet.

Comment: Most likely you are running low on memory. How much free memory and swap space do you have when this happens?

Comment: I saw the same issue today.  Previously, I was able to run HPROF with many stacktrace levels and `heap=sites`, but now I cannot.  Frustrating!